# Vertical lines appear on the black color

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one, hdmi

I have a new Xbox One S console (HDMI connection) and faint vertical lines appear on the black color:

[image]

**The image is only for demonstration purposes as the colors are completely off**, I had to take a picture of the screen using a camera because the artifacts don't appear in screenshots. I believe that only "pure black" (RGB 0) is affected as I haven't seen artifacts on other colors.

This is unlikely to be an issue with the monitor as I also use this screen with my computer (DVI connection) and blacks are displayed absolutely correctly.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to isolate what exactly is causing the issue. It could be the Xbox, or the HDMI, or the HDMI port. Do you have an extra display (monitor or TV) or an extra HDMI to test with?

Comment: @Virusbomb: Not at the time, but I will get or lend soon. I will also see if artifacts appear on the dashboard and in blu-ray video. I hope that some experienced members know what can cause artifacts like this in the first place.